# Operation between Fourier transform and convolution of locally integrable function

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory, convolution, schwartz-space

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $$ f(x_1, x_2)=(x_1+ix_2)^{n}.$$ We have $f \in S'$ because as $f \in L^{1}_{loc} (\mathbb{R}^{2})$ and $|f(x_1,x_2)|^{2} \le (1+|(x_1,x_2)|^{2})^{n}$ it is possible to show that $$ \varphi \in S \rightarrow \int f\varphi$$ defines a tempered distribution.

My problem is

> How can I show that $$\mathcal{F}{(x_1+ix_2)^{n}}=\mathcal{F}(x_1+ix_2)*\ldots *\mathcal{F}(x_1+ix_2)?$$

Notation:
S is the Schwartz space.

S' is the space of tempered distributions

$\mathcal{F}:S' \rightarrow S'$ is the Fourier transform.

$*$ is the convolution.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Right, it cannot be due to perfectly general properties of convolutions of tempered distributions... because general convolution is not defined, for one, and even in some simple situations where it is defined, it need not be associative, etc. :)  Probably best just to compute both sides of your desired equality and see that they do indeed match.